# PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I have successfully installed Laravel and it running in a `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. when I run the php artisan migrate it gives me the following error.

`PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=plantshop", "root", "", []) /Projects/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70`

I can able to access my php myadmin using http://192.168.64.2 port but not by `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` and one more thing is I have a lamp/htdocs/abc directory if I go to this link the page is not displaying and it says

`Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.`

I have tried changing the port number and directly pointed unix_socket to php myadmin but none of its working. what is wrong with my configuration? I am using a mac, could anyone help me out?

my .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=plantshop
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Databse.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,

            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Answer (score 2):

You're searching for the database at the address `127.0.0.1`, but you most likely configured it to use address `192.168.64.2`. In your `.env`, you need to direct `DB_HOST` to your actual DB server, in this case, `192.168.64.2`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case MySQL server is not running. Please restart the MySQL server, The issue will resolve.

if you are using an ubuntu server then run the below command.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```